# on xhr.send(), handle error due to Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, content-security-policy

I understand the purpose of some of these Origin Policies are there for a reason, such as preventing XSS, but I am hoping to handle errors better.

We inject an iframe into our visitors website, and in order to create a case, we are changing our code to `POST` an XMLHTTPRequest to our endpoint URL.

Some of our clients already have very specific CSPs (which they also configured to allow our existing, and soon to be outdated code) to handle our product being implemented.

So, now, when we POST, some sites will fail and I want to better handle that failure.  For example, if our client has `connect-src 'none'` the POST will fail and I want to fallback to the Legacy logic.

It doesn't seem like there is a specific failure code because on `xhr.send()` it immediately creates a console error `Refused to connect to 'http://blah.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'none'".`

Then, `xhr.onreadystatechange` event fires, and finally `xhr.onerror` event fires.  So if I am seeing things correctly, there is no specific get(Content-Security-Policy) method.  The Headers are empty, so is it correct that my only options are

```
if (this.status === 0 && !this.getAllResponseHeaders() && !this.responseText) {
  console.warn("This is probably blocked by CSP. Use Legacy method below, do not retry XHR.");
  callLegacyMethodHere();
}
```

Also, because I can track this on the onreadystatechange Event I do not need to run the onError event.  But there is no way to cancel this XHR?

We cannot use fetch() for promises because it's not supported in IE yet.  We only use pure JS (no `$.ajax()`).

Thank you for clarifying

1. better logic to know it's a failure from CSP and
2. can I just delete the XHR from inside the onreadystatechange?

Comment: Can you use fetch and fail down to this method in IE? Because IE doesn't respect CSP in any way anyway so this method would always work, for better or worse, in IE only.